# JPA 1.0: How to write an efficient transformer from an entity to a transfer object?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-1.0

I want to write an efficient transformer, that will transform a JPA (1.0) entity to my transfer object and that:

- will be called in a transactional context,
- will cause no extra DB interaction, that is will transform only what's already loaded.

I cannot use the construct `if (entity.getSomething() != null)` as "something" will get loaded.

The only thing I can think of is having the transformer spawn a new transaction, reload the entity in the new transaction's context and commit it — and then working on a detached entity. It does involve a reload, though. Any cleverer ideas?

Comment: Sounds like an EJB 1.0 anti-pattern to me.

Comment: @duffymo Please don't stray away from the topic, I'm not saying the application in question is an engineering masterpiece. If I could get rid of TOs, I would, but it's not doable within the time I have.

Comment: I doubt that the efficiency of creating the TO is the bottleneck in your app.  Write the naive implementation, profile it, and find out if you need something better.

Comment: @duffymo OK, I probably overexposed "efficient"; should be "lazy". My true reason for this is that the current transformer generates a lot of unneeded SELECTs that get deadlocked with RR locks - and there's no business case for these SELECTs, so they can be safely eliminated.

Comment: This is another reason why I don't get the ORM fetish.  It's more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/manual-tweaking-output.html) to transform your Entity[Implicitly `Serializable`]  to XML & to de-serialize back to object. It may not be the effcient one, but fast & easy to implement.

I am successfully using the same process for a project.

Comment: Hmmm, I haven't thought about that, thanks. It seems to be the only way to work around any proxy logic that JPA tool may generate. Do you think so?

Comment: No, it's not the only way. I am working on an another project where we are planning a more efficient way & let you if we become successful. Stay in touch.

Answer (score 1):

ORM proxy stuff can be helped with using Gilead.
http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/

Answer (score 0):

JPA provides a PersistenceUnitUtil class with an isLoaded() API that can be used to determine if a relationships is loaded.

Comment: I was asking SPECIFICALLY for JPA 1.0 - I know that 2.0 offers a lot more in terms of controlling and diagnosing entity states and persistence context. I cannot switch to 2.0, though.